# Gallery Image not fitting the screen in android

Tags: android, imageview, gallery

I am displaying a bunch of images in the Gallery View.

The layout is ,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:spacing="10dip" >
</Gallery>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgfromWebUrl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the custom adapter for loading images,

```
public View getView(int arg0, View paramView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    Log.d("","custom Adapter5");
    View localView;
    if (paramView == null) {
        localView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.property_image_adapter, null);
    } else {
        localView = paramView;
    }       
    ImageView imgfromWebUrl=(ImageView)localView.findViewById(R.id.imgfromWebUrl);          
    Log.d("", "pics[0]: "+pics);
    imgfromWebUrl.setImageBitmap(pics[arg0]);
    imgfromWebUrl.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imgfromWebUrl.setBackgroundResource(defaultItemBackground);
    imgfromWebUrl.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(200, 200));
    return imgfromWebUrl;
}
```

currently my image is shown as,

[image]

My image is fit to the center part of the screen. but I want the image to fit full screen,like this image

[image]

Please  help me out!!
 Any help is Appreciated!!

Comment: set your layout_width="match_parent" .

Comment: Do you want to remove the space around the image or you want image in a full view?

Comment: @Rushabh Patel, I want the image to fit the screen width regardless of height!!

Comment: Then you need to go with this property `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in your imageview.

Comment: I have already set the scaleType in adapter class!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue:**

Image is fitting to the parent.but your gallery params are fixed of 200.

**Solution:**

kindly remove that line.

```
imgfromWebUrl.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(200, 200));
```

and make this change in xml:

```
<Gallery
android:id="@+id/gallery1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:spacing="10dip" >
```

Comment: I removed the line but it causes this exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.linearlayout$layoutparams

Comment: kindly put your `imageview` and `gallery` in separate xml,then inflate the layout of `imageview` inside `getview` method

Answer (score 2):

Use this property `android:scaleType="fitXY"`  [Document for ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Answer (score 0):

Configure the layout parameters like so:

```
i.setLayoutParams( new
Gallery.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```