# Choose image from gallery and fit into ImageView box android

Tags: android, imageview, gallery

This might be similar question to other but not able to find satisfactory result .

so please help, I am developing an app which have `ImageView` box of `100dp` by `200dp` size, beside that I have a <kbd>CHOOSE IMAGE</kbd> button after selecting the  image from gallery it dose not appear in the ImageView box due to image size problem also there is no problem in code for image selection for gallery, if i select low size image then the above mention dimension the image appears perfectly.

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Here is the layout:**

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/index"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gallery Image not fitting the screen in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205781/gallery-image-not-fitting-the-screen-in-android)

Comment: Tried solution but not working.that's why re-initiated question hope image will help to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below parameter in your `ImageView`

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: Still its not working. I think some modification required in onActivityResult() method.